# Selecting an element after using children()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My selector `jQuery('.pa_availability-pin table tbody tr').children('td').eq(1);`
returns a `<td>` object
now I want to select the `<input>` element which is inside this selected `<td>`

How to do this in one statement?

Comment: You can `jQuery('.pa_availability-pin table tbody tr').children('td:eq(1)').find('input')`

Comment: Here is a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/m5JXQ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery('.pa_availability-pin table tbody tr > td:eq(1) > input');
```

However, we can optimize this a bit. `table tbody tr td` is redundant, since each of those elements *must* be contained in the other. You can safely reduce that to just `td`:

```
jQuery('.pa_availability-pin td:eq(1) > input'); // zero-based
```

Where `>` specifies a direct child, which is what you seemed to want.

Furthermore, [`:eq` isn't a CSS selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), so to optimize your selector use `:nth-child` instead:

```
jQuery('.pa_availability-pin td:nth-child(2) > input'); // not zero-based
```

If there's another element wrapped around your `input` (such as a label), just remove the `>` from the selector.

Answer (score 2):

Just combine it all into 1 selector:

```
jQuery('.pa_availability-pin table tbody tr td:eq(1) input');
```

Or use `.find()`

```
jQuery('.pa_availability-pin table tbody tr').children('td').eq(1).find('input');
```

Comment: Thanks for the first approach, ie., `jQuery('.pa_availability-pin table tbody tr td:eq(1) input');`